# Articulation of DAG between two Vertex sets

Tags: c++, boost, graph, graph-theory

I'm trying to solve a problem that I'm sure has been solved before, I just don't know what the solution in Graph Theory is.

I have a Graph G(V,E) that contains a Vertex Set START that have in-degree 0, and another Vertex Set END that have out-degree 0.
How can I find the minimal set of Vertices B in V but not in START or END that cause vertices START and END to become completely disconnected.

Note that this is a DAG so I don't believe Tarjan's Articulation algorithm applies.

Comment: @mangusta Not actually. Please see the sample DAG on wiki.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph

Answer (score 0):

I would dare to suggest a way, based on breadth-first search,

If we assume that there are node levels from 1 to N, in order to disconnect all start nodes from end nodes, at least one out of these N levels should be removed,
hence we simply need to find out the level with smallest number of nodes.

For instance in this picture below, level 1 and level N have six nodes each (we may need to consider some boundary conditions e.g. case if start node is directly connected to end node etc.):

[image]